# remove quotes around ONLY numeric values in string

Tags: javascript, string

```
var arr= '[{"a":"b","c":"521"}]';

let ds = arr.replace(/"(\d)"/g,"$1");

alert(ds);
```

Sample; I have tried the above along with various others.. cannot seem to get this to take effect on numeric values only..

Desired result would be:

```
[{"a":"b","c":521}]
```

i.e.

```
    let dss = JSON.stringify(arr);
    let ds = dss.replace(/"(\d)"/g,"$1");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd parse the JSON and use a reviver function to replace digit strings with just the digits:

```js
var arr= '[{"a":"b","c":"521"}]';
const parsed = JSON.parse(
  arr,
  (key, value) => typeof value === 'string' && /^\d+$/.test(value)
    ? Number(value)
    : value
);
console.log(JSON.stringify(parsed));
```

Comment: thanks.. almost, but it appears it is not including decimal vals? i.e. "38.97219723"

Comment: If decimals are a possibility, add optional decimals to the pattern: `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

Comment: That worked! however.... how could I handle to also take negative. i.e. "-33.21"

Comment: Add an optional `-` to the beginning of the pattern?

Comment: Such as ->      (-{1}?)^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$

Comment: Probably like this ey? /-?^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/

Comment: Put the optional dash after the `^` (at the beginning of the digits), else the pattern will never match. `^-?`

Answer (score 2):

```
let ds = arr.replace(/"(\d+)"/g,"$1");
```

add **+** before **\d** like: **(\d+)**

Comment: Correct answer, but you should add an explanation and make this a snippet

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is looking for one digit add a + for one or more

```js
var arr= '[{"a":"b","c":"521"}]';
let ds = arr.replace(/"(\d+)"/g,"$1");
console.log(ds);
```

Comment: still did not work for me... do I need to do it before the stringify not after?

Comment: Of course after, before it is not even a string.. it is a js object, anyway why wouldnt you changing the object normally without regex before the stringify?